# How can I concatenate the foreach function with something else?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to fill the empty array called `$Errors` with some items to make some restrictions on my uploading form.
So I'm trying to put a `<div>` tag as an item inside the array and that div tag holds some strings and I want to concatenate these strings with a `foreach` loop as shown in the code below but it keeps giving an error and I don't actually know how to concatenate a function like `foreach` with strings.

```
$Errors= array();
$Ext= array('jpg','png','jpeg','bmp','gif');
$FileName= $_FILES ['UploadedFile']['name'];
$FileExt=strtolower(end(explode(".",$FileName)));

if(!in_array($FileExt,$Ext)):
$Errors[]="<div>The file that you're uploading is " . $FileName . " And it is not an image file, only these file types are supported " . foreach($Ext as $AllowedExt):echo $AllowedExt;
endforeach;"</div>";endif;
```

Comment: Whats the error you get?

Comment: Might want to use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) instead of `foreach`

Comment: PHP doesn't like `end(explode())` https://3v4l.org/i95Qj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to loop over an array while your building a string is.. messy at best.

Build your string from the arrays content first and then concat that onto the rest of the string. You can also use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to convert an array into a string.

```
$Errors= array();
$Ext= array('jpg','png','jpeg','bmp','gif');
$ExtAsString =  implode(",", $Ext);
$FileName= $_FILES ['UploadedFile']['name'];
$FileExt=strtolower(end(explode(".",$FileName)));

if(!in_array($FileExt,$Ext)):
    $Errors[]="<div>The file that you're uploading is " . $FileName . " And it is not an image file, only these file types are supported " . $ExtAsString . "</div>";
endif;
```

Comment: No need to build the string FIRST when using implode

Comment: Well ok badly written let me edit, but the point is get the string built one way or another first

Comment: While not false, there's no need to build it first: `$test="<div>".implode(",", $Ext)."</div>";` would work fine.

Comment: PHP doesn't like this advice: https://3v4l.org/i95Qj

Comment: This code throws a `Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference`

Comment: @Zachary
tyvm now it looks much easier and works just fine

Comment: @brombeer
True, it also works just fine ty for the note.

Answer (score 0):

Write your foreach() statement as a separate function and concatenate it with your text.
And besides the items in your allowed extension isn't that too many to written directly in the text.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Consider adding code samples to explain your answer.

Comment: I'm just practicing this isn't a live project so the text isn't really getting my attention atm..ty for the note though